# How to install a distribution on Docker using ddev composer command?

Tags: 8, distributions

I am new to docker. I have to install [Openy](https://drupal.org/project/openy) distribution on docker using ddev CLI. ddev use this command to setup a normal Drupal 8 installation.

```
ddev composer create drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev --stability dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist
```

it's working fine. Now I have to install [openy](https://drupal.org/project/openy) on docker, composer command for [openy](https://drupal.org/project/openy) is:

```
composer create-project ymcatwincities/openy-project MY_PROJECT --no-interaction --no-dev
```

I tried writing `ddev` before openy command and many other changes are made but not successful. Now my main question is that, that how to install any other Drupal distribution using composer command on docker.

Answer (score 0):

Note difference. First the official command.

```
ddev composer create ...
```

And now the command you executed.

```
ddev composer create-project ...
```

See? DDEV provides its own command to create a project. So just adding `ddev` in front of any composer command doesn't always work. Instead it's `ddev composer create ...`.